# Why does it state "Disconnected" in my DBPg debugger plugin for Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++, xdebug

This question has to do with the `DBPg debugger` installed as a plugin on Notepad++. It's for debugging PHP code.  I've installed xDebug for PHP, and my phpinfo() outputs states the xDebug is installed.  I have PHP installed in:

`C:\PHP`

and the xDebug .dll file `php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.5-vc11.dll` installed in:

`C:\PHP\ext`

The `dbgpPlugin.dll` is in my Notepad++ plugins directory, and everything seems to be working fine except I have that `disconnected` status,

[image: Disconnected status in drop down field]

and my stepping buttons won't activate. They remain grayed out.  I'm wondering if it is because of the plugin configuration.  I'm not sure what the `Local Path` and `Remote Path` settings are for, or what to set them to.

[image]

Right now, I have the Remote page set to the path that my Apache server is configured to point to.  `C:\Users\Gigabyte\MyWebserer`
But, I'm not sure if that's what I'm supposed to put in there.  Should the remote path point to the Apache program folder instead?  The PHP program folder?  I don't know.